# Am I lifting too much too fast?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, workout-routines, muscle

My goal is getting bigger muscles
I am 6'4" tall and 43 years old man

I have been training for a year now

When I look at the weights I lift compared to the other guys in the gym (the big muscles guys) I notice that I lift way more than they do.

they have much bigger muscles than I do, and they are younger but they don't lift as much as I do.

Am I going too much too fast?

Shall I reduce the weight and not push myself as hard I am now?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is your goals with regards to strength training. Are you wanting to focus on big bursts of strength like a power lifter? Are you wanting to focus on big muscles like a body builder? Are you wanting to focus on building a lean athletic body? These things have different strategies for how you train while in the gym. Telling us your goals will help us to understand your situation better.

Comment: @JustSnilloc Thanks, my first sentence is declaring my goal which is getting but muscles like a body builder.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part here I think is to look how these other guys in the gym are performing their lifts and comparing it to how you're doing the same exercises. Are they doing very strict reps? How are your reps?

If for example you do bicep curls with 50lbs while swining with your upper body, you'll be working the bicep a lot less compared to doing only 30lbs but very strict reps.

Weight in this matter is less important in some ways. Obviously you need to have progressive overload, but that doesn't always mean going ultra heavy. You need to find the balance to doing reps with good contraction and time under tension, and doing a heavy enough weight.

Answer (score 0):

- Some people are naturally denser than others you may have bigger muscles with smaller bone structure.
- Another factor could be that your form is not as strict as others, bodybuilders aim to achieve hypertrophy by keeping time under tension higher and controlling the weights.

> Should I slow down?

The answer is no, if that weight is comfortable for you and you're certain your form is strict then just continue the way you're going. It could be down to your weight as well they could just appear bigger by being more trim. Although its not always good to talk about but genetics can play a huge part in the size that you are and your bodily composition as well. It all depends but you should **always** aim to push yourself...